# JSON.stringify = illegal access

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have an array with objects in Javascript. I want to save this array to a `.json` file.

Before I added the objects to the file, I `console.log` the objects.

```
// Client
Object {id: "1", color: "#00FF00"}
Object {id: "2", color: "#FF7645"}
Object {id: "3", color: "#FF8845"}
```

Then I post the jsonArray to my nodejs server like this:

```
// Client
$.post('/savejson', 'json=' + JSON.stringify(jsonArray)) // This works
```

Catch the post and save the file in nodejs like this:

```
app.router.post('/savejson', function(data) {
    url = '/jsonfiles/something.json'
    // Nodejs Server
    fs.writeFile(url, data.body.json, function(error) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error)
            return
    }
    console.log('Saved file: ' + url)
})
```

Now I have a json file with an array with objects like this:

### something.json

```
[
    {"id":"1","color":"#00FF00"},
    {"id":"2","color":"#FF7645"},
    {"id":"3","color":"#FF8845"}
]
```

I read the file like this:

```
// Nodejs Server
jsonfile = fs.readFileSync(url, 'UTF-8')
// Output jsonfile: 
[{"id":"1","color":"#00FF00"},{"id":"2","color":"#FF7645"},{"id":"3","#FF8845"}]
```

Parse it

```
// Nodejs Server
jsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonfile)
// Output jsonArray: 
[{id: '1',color: '#00FF00'},{ id: '2',color: '#FF7645'},{ id: '3',color: '#FF8845'}]
```

And send back to the client

```
// Nodejs Server
window.newjson(jsonArray)
```

At my client I catch the file with:

```
// Client
window.newjson = function(jsonArray) {
    // Here foreach loop
}
// Output jsonArray:
undefined[3]
    0: 
        color: "#00FF00"
        id: "1"
        __proto__: 
    1: 
        color: "#FF7645"
        id: "2"
        __proto__: 
    2: 
        color: "#FF8845"
        id: "3"
        __proto__: 
    length: 3
    __proto__: undefined[0]
```

And for each object I `console.log` the object.

### Output

```
// Client
{id: "1", color: "#00FF00"}
{id: "2", color: "#FF7645"}
{id: "3", color: "#FF8845"}
```

Noticed the Object word is difference.

Now I want the same file to be saved again like this:

```
// Client
$.post('/savejson', 'json=' + JSON.stringify(jsonArray)) // Not working anymore...
```

When I use `JSON.stringify(jsonArray)` at client side, I get the error: `Uncaught illegal access`

I also tried to use `JSON.parse(jsonArray)` at client side, but this one give me the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`

When I log the jsonArray BEFORE the second post:

```
// 1
console.log(jsonArray)

// Result
Array[3]
    0: 
        color: "#00FF00"
        id: "1"
        __proto__: 
    1: 
        color: "#FF7645"
        id: "2"
        __proto__: 
    2: 
        color: "#FF8845"
        id: "3"
        __proto__: 
    length: 3
    __proto__: Array[0] 


// 2
console.log(jsonArray.toString())

// Result
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]


// 3
JSON.stringify(jsonArray)

// Result
Uncaught illegal access


// 4
JSON.parse(jsonArray)

// Result
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

What did I wrong? Why I'm missing the `Object` word?

Comment: Not much we can do without seeing the code. Sounds like you're calling `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` on the wrong things.

Comment: I wouldn't want to see anywhere close to all of it; only the parts where you save to, and then read from, your .json file.

Comment: Obviously this means that you are doing something wrong when parsing/stringifying. Are you by any chance using `stringify` in a loop? It seems that your objects are actually strings. Have a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2z3Qq/1/ I.E. I think `window.newjson` is the culprit. Or maybe the way you pass the data to it is broken.

Comment: Where are semicolons?

Comment: So, show us the code where you create `jsonArray` on NodeJS side, which then you pass to `window.newjson`.

Comment: @Oleg, they are unnecessary

Comment: @freakish The jsonArray is created client side, sent by `$.post` to the server and the server sends it back using the `window.newjson`

Comment: @Bondye http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript

Comment: @Bondye Obviously it's impossible, because he cannot pass an object from server to client. He has to stringify it somewhere. The code snippet is incomplete and I have a feeling that there's a mistake there.

Comment: @Bondye Where is the code that stringifies `jsonArray` on the server side?

Comment: @Bondye You've written that you read the file like this (on the server side): `jsonfile = fs.readFileSync(url, 'UTF-8')` then you parse it (on the server side) `jsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonfile)` and then you send it back to client `window.newjson(jsonArray)`. And I'm asking: where did you stringify `jsonArray`? In other words: how are you sending the data back? P.S. Sorry, for some reason I thought that you're not the OP. :/

Comment: I sent the data back to the window (using appjs). `window.newjson` on server side call the function `window.newjson = function()` on client side, I just pass the jsonArray as parameter. So I need to stringify the parameter?

Comment: @freakish Wow, thats it!! A jsonArray as parameter must be stringified and parsed again .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to stringify `jsonArray` before sending it back to the client side.

Comment: @Bondye No problem. That's a general rule that you have to stringify everything before sending it to the client/server.

Answer (score 0):

The unexpected token problem could be because you are calling JSON.parse on a JavaScript Object as mentioned here:
[d3.js json uncaught syntax error unexpected token o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636084/d3-js-json-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-o) .
Then for JSON.stringify(jsonArray) at client side where you get the error "Uncaught illegal access", debug by checkking if jsonArray is null(as null is an object still):

```
if(variable==null){
// Do stuff console.log etc
}
```

(although it is very rare for this to be a problem .strigify should print null)
If this fails your variable could also be undeclared. I think the problem could be what @Anthony Grist said initially

Comment: My variable is an array with objects. And its never null. I check for this because I need at least 1 id.

Comment: What happens if you do: JSON.stringify(jsonArray[0]);
is it still Uncaught illegal access ?

Comment: No, when I use the `JSON.stringify(jsonArray[0])` it displays `{"id":"1","color":"#00FF00"}`