# Why is illegal access appearing in my node log?

Tags: node.js, express

Recently, we've been getting "illegal access" appearing in our application log. The application is node 0.12.7 with express 4.13.1. We are running angular on the frontend. The illegal access appears in the log and is also displayed on the web page. None of the other script files load when this occurs. It started happening seeming randomly on 11/6/2015. I've exhaustively scanned the log files searching for a culprit and it does nto appear that user activity or lack of system resources (memory, disk, io, cpu) have anything to do with the issue. Once the illegal access error occurs, it requires a re-start of the application (currently pm2 is being used on the server to call node). Running pm2 version 0.15.7. Did not upgrade any of these pieces of software just prior to the issues starting.

Comment: Here are a couple things that can lead to an "illegal access" error: https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2397 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833784/json-stringify-illegal-access.  Some causes of this error have been fixed in node 4+.

Comment: I discovered a procedure to duplicate the error. Hopefully by EOD, I'll be able to post the solution. I believe it has something to do with JSON.Parse() / JSON.Stringify() at this point.